# Combine two panda series of the same data frame with different lengths

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Data frame which consist of multiple Pandas series . I want to combine three series with different lengths .

My data frame looks like this:

```
X message Main table: 
       _tunneled     _iTOW  _messageIndex  version  numSv  
0            0.0  518431.0         1387.0      2.0    8.0            
0
1            0.0  518431.0         1388.0      2.0    8.0      
1
2            0.0  518432.0         1443.0      2.0    8.0          
2
3            0.0  518432.0         1444.0      2.0    8.0          
3
4            0.0  518433.0         1488.0      2.0    8.0         
4
...          ...       ...            ...      ...    ...      
14333        0.0  525597.0       307330.0      2.0   19.0     
14334        0.0  525598.0       307370.0      2.0   19.0     
14335        0.0  525598.0       307371.0      2.0   19.0     
14336        0.0  525599.0       307411.0      2.0   19.0     
14337        0.0  525599.0       307412.0      2.0   19.0     


[280550 rows x 41 columns]Sub-table svData:
        epochIx     _iTOW  _parentMessageIndex  ionoEst  ionoEstAcc  svDataGnssId  svDataSvId  svStatus  
0           1.0  518432.0               1387.0   0.0000      0.0269           2.0         9.0       7.0        
1           1.0  518432.0               1387.0   0.0000      0.0156           2.0        10.0       7.0       
2           1.0  518432.0               1387.0   0.0000      0.0210           2.0         4.0       7.0        
3           1.0  518432.0               1387.0   0.0000      0.0289           2.0        36.0       7.0        
4           1.0  518432.0               1387.0   0.0000      0.0156           2.0         2.0       7.0        
...         ...       ...                  ...      ...         ...           ...         ...       ...     
280545  14338.0  525600.0             307412.0   0.0114      0.0109           2.0        34.0       3.0      
280546  14338.0  525600.0             307412.0   0.0408      0.0108           0.0         3.0       3.0       
280547  14338.0  525600.0             307412.0  -0.0119      0.0100           2.0        11.0       3.0        
280548  14338.0  525600.0             307412.0  -0.0053      0.0096           0.0        17.0       3.0       
280549  14338.0  525600.0             307412.0  -0.0758      0.0106           0.0         1.0       3.0
```

I want to combine **numSv** from Main table , **_iTOW** and **svDataSvId** from Sub-table **svData**

I tried to use concat method but it gives me error: TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "Series"

```
x=pd.concat(sv_id, msg)
```

Any pointers

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for a [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html)?

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem! You need to encapsulate the dataframes in a list:

```
x = pd.concat([sv_id, msg])
```

Comment: Hi , I tried that but it is basically appending the series one after another . I would like to have them as two separate columns

Comment: Ok, so if I'm understanding correctly you want a new dataframe with three columns: main_table["numSv"], svData["_iTOW"] and svData["svDataSvId"]. Do the tables have the same index? How do you want the values to be filled in the shorter series? main_table[["numSv"]].join(svData[["iTow", "svDataSvld"]], how = "outer") would fill the shorter series with NaN. If you use how = "inner" the extra length would be removed from the longer series